# I want to use ELU to find out if something is unusual but correct usage: is that OK?

Tags: discussion

I want to use ELU to find out if something is unusual but correct usage: *is that OK*?

So not whether it sounds natural, but if the sentence conveys the meaning I intend, and whether that is *not* proscribed in any existing (rather than imagined) prescriptive grammars. Ideally with an explanation of **why** it isn't proscribed.

Does that make sense and is it a misuse of the site?

Comment: Do remember that many questions that may not be suitable for the Q&A would be happily entertained on chat.

Answer (score 1):

ELU, like other Stack Exchange sites, is designed to produce *the correct answer*, rather than the musings (or varying value) found on internet fora. So as long as you can clearly define 'correct' and explain where your phrase would be used, I don't see a problem with this (though you may find the former requirement easier said than done).

"Why it isn't proscribed", though, is probably unanswerable. English wasn't designed using a set of meta-rules*; if a phrase makes sense and does not breach the codified rules that avoid ambiguity and assist the audience (whichever code you subscribe to), it's legitimate.

- *Except in the sense that when the Tower of Babel fell, certain peoples were granted the English language as a special favour; all others had to make do with inferior tongues*.

Comment: I repeat that you phrase it so that it has a (potential) correct answer. If it can't be fitted into that Procrustean bed, it is not a proper SE question and will be closed. (As choster pointed out, such queries are often welcome on chat.)